# Cant properly stringify array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to serialize a form and submit it, however I've been beating my head since last night because I can't replace some backlash in my string.

Considering following array:

```
files = ["1406822377238.jpg", "1406822385416.jpg"]
```

when I stringify its value to set it an input like so:

```
$('#images').val(JSON.stringify(files));
```

the value for the input becomes

```
value=​"["1406822377238.jpg","1406822385416.jpg"]​`
```

to removed the brackets which I don't need I do this:

```
$('#images').val("" + $('#images').val().slice(1,-1) + "");
```

and then input value becomes

```
value=​""1406822377238.jpg","1406822385416.jpg""
```

now to remove the beginning and ending double quotes I do this:

```
 $('#images').val("" + $('#images').val().slice(1,-1) + "");
```

now my input value is

```
value=​"1406822377238.jpg","1406822385416.jpg"
```

which seems fine in the console but in my db I get this, why?

```
"image": [
     "1406823278844.jpg\",\"1406823281193.jpg" 
  ]
```

I expect this.

```
"image": [
     "1406823278844.jpg","1406823281193.jpg" 
  ]
```

I tried this to remove the backslash `$('#images').val($('#images').val().replace(/\\/g, ''));` but didn't work.

Comment: When you have to write 10 hacks to get around a built in language function, useually you are trying to do something stupid. I didnt downvote though

Comment: How about you explain why you are doing all this - eg what is the big picture

Comment: Why not just `$('#images').val(files.join(", "));` ??

Comment: I did say I'm serializing a form to submit. Everything is working fine other than what I just described. big picture? trying to get from here "1406823278844.jpg\",\"1406823281193.jpg" to here "1406823278844.jpg","1406823281193.jpg".

Comment: @fpena06 it would help if you'd say exactly what you want the value of that input field to be.

Comment: So your endpoint expects images to be a single (comma separated)string?

Comment: @Pointy I would like the value to be an array of images like files is. I somewhat have what I need expect I get these backlash "1406823278844.jpg\",\"1406823281193.jpg"

Comment: The backslashes are escaping the ".

Comment: @user574632 endpoint expects image: [{type: String}]

Comment: Well it **is** an array at the very beginning, right before you start hacking it up with string functions. jSON.stringify(array); does exactly what it says

Comment: If I didn't stringify and just set like this '$('#images').val(files)' my value would be "1406824103456.jpg,1406824105973.jpg" which is one string. I'm simply trying to get all the values from files array and assign it to $('#images').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the endpoint expects form-encoded data, that’s what you need to use. Passing a list of values for a key is just specifying that key twice:

```
image=1406822377238.jpg&image=1406822385416.jpg
```

You’ll need multiple `<input>` elements to do this in a `<form>`. Assuming they’re hidden:

```
var form = $('#my-form');

form.find('input[name=image]').remove();

form.append(files.map(function (file) {
    return $('<input>', { type: 'hidden', name: 'image', value: file });
});
```

And if the endpoint is PHP, it’ll expect the name `image[]` instead of `image`.